# Finding the longest words in a text file

Tags: python

I have created a function to find the longest word in a text file and finding the longest word(s) in a text file that can be made from 9 letters. I'm new to python and I'm creating a game similar to countdown.

I've created a function to find the longest word in the text file. What I want now is to create python code to find the longest word(s) that can be formed from the 9 letters.

Each letter can only be used once. So from 'qugteroda', I should get rag outed, outraged, out dare, out read, outrage,readout. I'm using python 2.2

```
    def Words():
           qfile=open('dict.txt','r')
           longg=''
           for line in qfile:
           if len(line)>len(longg):
             longg=line
           return longg
```

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.2? Are you sure it's 2.2?

Comment: You can write a permutation algorithm, but, Python has no concept of which permutations will be a valid English word.

Comment: @adchilds. thats why i am using the file dict.txt which is a dictionary

Comment: Do you have a dictionary or a list of valid english words to compare to?

Comment: @MalC, so the longest possible word and the longest possible word(s) from the previous longest possible word are all in the same file (dict.txt)?

Comment: Your Python is 10 years old now, please update to 2.7.4 (should go painless)

Comment: Please clarify this question; the title appears to contradict the actual question content. I suggested an edit, but it was considered too major to accept; feel free to use it as a suggestion for how to improve this question, though. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2046682

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of longest word in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637696/length-of-longest-word-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_words(valid_letters):
    valid_letters = Counter(valid_letters)

    with open('dict.txt', 'r') as handle:
        for word in handle:
            letters = Counter(word.strip())

            if valid_letters >= letters:
                yield word

longest_word = max(find_words('qugteroda'), key=len)
```

The gist of it is that you count what letters are in your word. Something like this:

```
>>> count_letters('test')
{'t': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1}
```

And then check to see if every one of those letters is in your valid letters dict (making sure that the counts are also equal to or smaller than the allowed counts).

Then, you just find the longest word.

To find the longest *combination* of words, make a recursive function that builds chains of words that fit within your letter constraints.

Comment: This answer is clever, complete, and correct, and probably faster than the other solutions given so far. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use itertools to get the permutation:

```
list(itertools.permutations("qugteroda")
```

and for every element in the list, check if that word exists in the dictionary file.

You can check [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for fast lookup in the dctionary.

Comment: This could be insanely slow, since permutations are `O(n!)`.

Answer (score 0):

1/  create a sorted string from the letters :

```
qugteroda ->  adegoqrtu
the_letters = 'adegoqrtu'
```

2/ Create a list from all the words in your word file, the list should have words with largest length at beginning, and smaller ones in the end, this will fasten your search for N largest words.

eg. `international, ragouted,facebook,outraged, outdare, outread, outrage,readout`

This list of words will not contain the words as is, but contain the sorted representation of the words. Store this search_dict in cache or file for further use.

eg. `search_dict = ['aaeiilnnnortt' , 'adegortu' ,'abcefkoo','adegortu']`

3/ To find N largest words, just loop through search_dict, and keep adding words which are a subset of the characters in `the_letters` string.
You can exit the loop once N words have been found.

Comment: This is somewhat clever, but unfortunately even despite sorting there's no guarantee that the dictionary words will be substrings of `the_letters`. Consider the case where the dictionary contains the single string `ac` and the letters are `abc`. `ac` is valid, but this algorithm will reject it.

Comment: @KyleStrand Thanks for picking up that big bug, added a correction that instead of substring,it should be a subset of the characters of the_letters. Rest of the method remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def longest_word(filename):
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
          words = infile.read().split()
print(words)    #  return list ['What', 'is', 'Python', 'language?', 'Python', ……..]
max_len = len(max(words, key=len))
return [word for word in words if len(word) == max_len]
print(longest_word('test.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    data=file.read().split()
    max=len(max(data,key=len ))
    print(max)
    res=[word for word in data if len(word)==max]
    print(res)
```

Comment: Please explain your code. How does this solve the issue the OP has?

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Demo.TXT", mode="r", encoding="utf8")
file = file.read().split()
lenght = 0
Longest_word = ""
for word in file:
    if len(word) > lenght:
        lenght = len(word)
        Longest_word = word

print(Longest_word, lenght)
```

Comment: I am trying to get 5 longest word from a text file but i only get one longest word . Anyone can tellme what am i doing wrong

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is a year old now but, try this:

'''Write a function find_longest_word() that takes a list of words and
returns the length of the longest one.'''

```
a = ['mamao', 'abacate', 'pera', 'goiaba', 'uva', 'abacaxi', 'laranja', 'maca']


def find_longest_word(a):

    d = []
    for c in a:
        d.append(len(c))
        e = max(d)  #Try "min" :D
    for b in a:
        if len(b) == e:
            print "Length is %i for %s" %(len(b), b)
```