# zip up two list of different lengths in elisp

Tags: elisp

I have two lists:

```
(setq x (list "a" "b" "c"))
(setq y (list "1" "2" "3" "4"))
```

How can I create a list of cons cells `(("a" . "1") ("b" . "2") ("c" . "3") ("a" . "4"))` with the shorter list recycled?

Comment: I actually thought the circular list was helpful in this case; it turns not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-mapcar #'list (setcdr (last x) x) y)
```

I'd add a check for which of them is larger, but that would spoil the brevity:).

Comment: But if you don't want the original lists *modified* then use `copy-sequence` on the shorter of `x` and `y`, and then use `setcdr` on that new list.

Answer (score 1):

There is surely a simpler way to do it, but here's a version that turns the input sequences into infinite lists and zips them together:

```
(defun* cycle-iterator (xs &optional (idx 0) (len (length xs)))
  "Create an iterator that will cycle over the elements in XS.
Return a cons, where the car is the current value and the cdr is
a function to continue the iteration."
  (cons (nth (mod idx len) xs)
        (eval `(lambda () (cycle-iterator ',xs ,(1+ idx) ,len)))))

(defun cycle-take (xs n)
  "Take N elements from XS, cycling the elements if N exceeds the length of XS."
  (loop
   when (plusp n)
   ;; Creating the iterator returns the first value. Subsequent calls can then
   ;; be processed in a loop.
   with (value . iterator) = (cycle-iterator xs)
   with acc = (list value)
   repeat (1- n) do (destructuring-bind (val . next) (funcall iterator)
                      (setq iterator next)
                      (setq acc (cons val acc)))
   finally (return (nreverse acc))))

(defun cycling-zip (xs ys)
  "Zip XS and YS together, cycling elements to ensure the result
  is as long as the longest input list."
  (loop
   with limit = (max (length xs) (length ys))
   for x in (cycle-take xs limit)
   for y in (cycle-take ys limit)
   collect (cons x y)))


;; Usage:
(cycling-zip '("a" "b" "c") '("1" "2" "3" "4"))
; => (("a" . "1") ("b" . "2") ("c" . "3") ("a" . "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library. Before attacking your problem, it's good to *find the length of the longest list*. The first way I came up with is:

```
(require 'dash)
(require 'dash-functional)
(length (-max-by (-on '> 'length) (list x y))) ; 4
```

[`-on`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-on-operator-transformer) is a smart function from package `dash-functional` that accepts a comparator, a key on which to compare, and returns a function that compares on this key. Therefore `(-max-by (-on '> 'length) xs)` finds an element in `xs`, whose *length* is biggest. But this expression is too smart for its own sake, and `dash-functional` only works in Emacs 24 due to lexical scoping. Let's rewrite it, inspired by [Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637696/596361):

```
(-max (-map 'length (list x y))) ; 4
```

To take first `n` elements from an infinite [cycled](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-cycle-list) list, do `(-take n (-cycle xs))`. Therefore to create an alist, where elements from a smaller list are cycled, write:

```
(let ((len (-max (-map 'length (list x y)))))
  (flet ((cycle (xs) (-take len (-cycle xs))))
    (-zip (cycle x) (cycle y)))) ; (("a" . "1") ("b" . "2") ("c" . "3") ("a" . "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the recursive approach that seemed natural for lisp.

```
(defun zip (xs ys)
  (cond
   ((or (null xs) (null ys)) ())
   (t (cons (cons (car xs) (car ys)) (zip (cdr xs) (cdr ys))))))
```