# List max() Method

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, types

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637696/length-of-longest-word-in-a-list). I have also read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) about max() method, but I don't understand what is the difference between these two

```
len(max(name_of_the_list))

len(max(name_of_the_list, key=len))
```

if we want to get the longest item in our list.

Comment: Only the later will output the length of the longest item in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first will compare the strings, and whichever is found alphabetically greatest, output its length (default behavior of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)).

The second will use the string's length as a key for the `max` function, and find the string with maximum length, and output its length. Here, the `len` refers to the python builtin [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function.

So both of these are not the same. Since you want to get the longest item in the list, use the second one as it is correct.

As a demo, consider the following

```
>>> name_of_the_list = ["abcdefgh", "ijkl"]
>>> max(name_of_the_list)
"ijkl"
>>> len(max(name_of_the_list))
4
>>> max(name_of_the_list, key=len)
"abcdefgh"
>>> len(max(name_of_the_list, key=len))
8
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify what the elements of the list are. Using strings as an example makes the discussion much more concrete.

Comment: I assumed they were strings because otherwise the `len` can throw `TypeError` in second example. Also, it doesn't make much sense to compare strings to integers or such.

Comment: @ mu 無 How can I know which one is "alphabetically greater". Can you describe this term? I mean, not in code, but me as a person, what is criteria for that?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić ["alphabetically greater"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) will be the same as [dictionary ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_order) or [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 2):

The function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) will use the function [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) defined by the type to check which one is the greatest. With the parameter `key` you can override this behavior specifying the function that need to be applied in order to compute the *score* of an item, in base of which `max` will return the maximum.

```
max(name_of_the_list, key=len)
```

This will return the longest item in the list (the one whose `len` returns the biggest number).

If `name_of_the_list` contains strings, omitting the `key` results in using the default `cmp` function defined for the strings which is the alphabetical comparison.

The `max` function will return the *element* which has the biggest key function, so if you wrap the call in another `len(...)` you are getting the length of that element. In order to obtain that, it means that you don't need the information about the element anymore but only the maximum of the keys, so you could do:

```
max(len(x) for x in name_of_the_list)
```

of also the equivalent using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
max(map(len, name_of_the_list))
```

This way, you will tell python to compute the length of the elements and then return the max of these lengths.