# Return length of longest word - Python

Tags: python

I am doing a Python course and am stuck on this question:

"Write a function called length_of_longest_word that accepts one list variable called word_list as an argument and returns the length of the longest word in that list."

Below is what I have written, appreciate your feedback!

```
    def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
        max_length = 0
        for max_length in word_list:
            max_length = max(max_length, length_of_longest_word)
        return max_length
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Length of longest word in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637696/length-of-longest-word-in-a-list)

Comment: "Appreciate your feedback" is not a Stack Overflow question.  Please repeat the intro tour.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. You have to use the actual built-in `len` somewhere:

```
def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
    max_length = 0
    for word in word_list:
        max_length = max(max_length, len(word))
    return max_length
```

You can also use some short-cuts, e.g. apply `max` on a longer iterable like all the lengthes at once:

```
def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
    return max(map(len, word_list), default=0)
```

Some links to docs: [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max` with *key* parameter.

```
max(map(len,word_list))
```

Which is equivalent to

```
max(len(word) for word in word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this approach

```
def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
    max_length = 0
    for word in word_list:
        length = len(word)
        if length > max_length:
            max_length = length
    return length
```